# pytest-bdd need to use data table format in feature file a

Tags: pytest, pytest-bdd

I am new to pytest-bdd framework.

Below is sample feature file Content:

```
Scenario: Sample scenario
    Given The following details:
      no | details1                 | detail2     |
       1 | something1               | a1          |
       2 | something2               | b2          |
       3 | something3               | c2          |
    When I search for no 2
    Then the response is :
      | details1                 | detail2 |
      | something2               | b2      |
```

i need to create a step definition which can utilize this data  as shown as below sample. i don't see much support of data table in pytest-bdd. is there any workaround for this?:

```
     @scenario('example.feature', )
     def test_sample_scenario():
        pass


    @given('Given The following details')
    def details_data():
        pass


    @when('I search for no 2')
    def i_search_for():
        pass

    @then('Then the response is')
    def reponse_is():
      pass
```